# The numbers of Triangles in a graph equals $\frac{1}{6}tr(A^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

The numbers of Triangles in a graph equals $\frac{1}{6}tr(A^3)$ where A is a square n x n Adjacency Matrix. The proof that is presented in the textbook, Applications of linear algebra, from chapter 13, graph theory is as follows:

Proof. A walk of Length 3 from a vertex to itself is a triangle and the triangle actually yields two walks, one in each direction. It follows that if a vertex $i$ is contained in a triangle, then $(A^3)_{ii} = 2$. From there we see that $tr(A^3)$ equals twice the number of vertices contained in the triangles. However, since each triangle contains three vertices it follows that $tr(A^3)$ equals six times the number of triangles.

The author poses a question right after this proof asking the reader why the same approach above does not work for squares, pentagons, etc. What this means is why doesn't the number of squares in a graph equal  $Mtr(A^4)$ where M is some constant, and similarly for higher-order shapes.  My thought process is that a walk of length 4 from a vertex to itself need not be a square, nor does a walk of length 5, etc. I am not quite sure if I am on the right track, and was wondering if someone could give any insight as to why this is the case.

Note: the original proof comes from a textbook written by one of the (great) Math teachers at my university, I will leave a link to the book as it is free: [https://www.math.umd.edu/~immortal/MATH401/](https://www.math.umd.edu/%7Eimmortal/MATH401/)

Comment: Your thought process is fine but you should write down an explicit example. For walks of length $4$ a hint is that walk of length $4$ can look like $v_1 \to v_2 \to v_1 \to v_2 \to v_1$ which fails to be a square because the vertices aren't distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

In general, the $(i, j)^{\text{th}}$ entry of the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of the adjacency matrix, $A^{n}$, represents the number of walks of length $n$ from $i$ to $j$. In other words, the $(i, j)^{\text{th}}$ entry in $A^{3}$ represents the number of walk of length $3$ in the underlying graph.

The argument works for triangles because a walk of length $3$ because this same symmetry guarantee is not there for higher-order shapes.

By the way, I read the same book when I took MATH 401 :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the reason it doesn't work for higher order shapes is because a path can go through some vertices more than once and make it back to the starting vertex with a length of 4+

Imagine the path/cycle length is 4. It could have a parallelogram sequence
$$ V_i V_j V_k V_mV_i.$$

However it could just be a walk which alternates between two vertices, not producing this shape. However, in a matrix the number will be representing the number of all the possible sequences, as opposed to just the number of paths (when no vertices are visited more than once)
$$V_iV_jV_iV_jV_i$$